# How do i Merge two dataframes in python Pandas? Why some values are getting skipped when merging is done?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Here there are three dataframes: `energy`, `ScimEn` and `GDP`.
Before I merge `energy` and `ScimEn` I tried printing `energy` and I am getting all 227 values. When I tried printing `ScimEn` I am getting all the values according to the rank (from 1 to 15).  However, once I call the merge function based on country it's skipping the first four rankings. Also, it starts from ranking 5. I am not able to debug the code.
Please ignore the comments as I have tried printing everything at every point of time as a part of debugging.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def answer_one():
    energy = pd.read_excel ('Energy Indicators.xls',skiprows=17,skip_footer=(38))
    energy=energy[[2,3,4,5]]
    energy.columns=['Country','Energy Supply','Energy Supply per Capita','% Renewable']
    energy=energy.replace('...',np.NaN)
    #print(energy.columns)
    energy['Energy Supply']=1000000*energy['Energy Supply']
    energy['Country']=energy['Country'].replace({"Republic of Korea": "South Korea"})
    energy['Country']=energy['Country'].replace({"United States of America": "United States"})
    energy['Country']=energy['Country'].replace({"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom"})
    energy['Country']=energy['Country'].replace({"China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"})
    energy['Country']=energy['Country'].str.replace(r"\(.\)","")
    #print(energy)
    GDP=pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv',skiprows=4)
    GDP=GDP[[0,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59]]
    GDP=GDP.rename(columns={'Country Name':'Country'})
    #print(GDP.columns)
    #print(GDP)
    ScimEn=pd.read_excel('scimagojr-3.xlsx')
    #print(ScimEn)
    ScimEn=ScimEn[:15]
    #print(ScimEn)
    new_df=pd.merge(ScimEn,energy,how='inner',left_on='Country',right_on='Country')
    #print(new_df)
    #print(df1.sort_values('Rank',ascending=True))
    new_df_final=pd.merge(new_df,GDP,how='inner',left_on='Country',right_on='Country')
    #print(new_df_final.columns)
    #new_df_final=new_df_final.sort_values('Rank',ascending=True)
    #new_df_final=new_df_final[:15]
    new_df_final=new_df_final.set_index('Country')
    #print(final_df)
    return new_df_final
answer_one()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are performing Inner join between those 3 dataframes (energy, ScimEn and GDP) on Country column. Inner join only gives rows that has matching country in all the 3 dataframes. your data might not have a matching country in first 4 rankings.

I can help you more if you can display each individual dataframe and merged one.

Comment: i have edited in the post .. can you please check it once again?

Comment: Can you display first 5 records of every data frame that you are working on. 
print(energy.head()) 
print(ScimEn.head())
print(GDP.head())
print(new_df.head())
print(new_df_final())

Comment: You are using Inner Join here in the Merge statement. Inner join only gives you matched records. if you want to have each and every record in your final merged dataframe use outer join instead. new_df=pd.merge(ScimEn,energy,how='outer',left_on='Country',right_on='Country')  new_df_final=pd.merge(new_df,GDP,how='outer',left_on='Country',right_on='Country')

Comment: It has so many columns which makes it confusing to post the output here.. I tried using head(). I will try to  use outer join and see the output

Comment: But China is present in the country column of both the dataframes.. so they are eligible for intersection right? The other values should show NaN. if use Outer its going to give all the values which actually i dont need